# Should frameworks and framework tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-merge

Should [frameworks](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frameworks) and [framework](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/framework) tags be merged?

I think so. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looked through the list, looks fine, merged.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas.